Strapi 404 Error when trying to update an address record: Problem with PUT API
In strapi I have a collection called user and another collection called address, both are related (a user can have many addresses) and both are created by Content-Type Builder. From nextjs I try to update, find and delete an address, the problem is that when I send the petition to the api it always sends me a 404 error.
In the authenticated role I have all permissions activated (put, create, delete, find and findOne).
This is an example of how I want to update a data
 const { id } = await req.json();
        const payload = {
            data: {
                is_main: true,
            },
        };
        const authToken = await getAuthToken();
        if (!authToken) NextResponse.json({ message: 'Unauthorized' }, { status: 401 });
        const responseData = await mutateData("PUT", `/api/addresses/${Number(id)}`, payload,);
        console.log("responseData ", responseData);
        if (responseData) {
            return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Address deleted successfully' }, { status: 200 });
        }


In the console.log it show me this
responseData  {
  data: null,
  error: {
    status: 404,
    name: 'NotFoundError',
    message: 'Not Found',
    details: {}
  }



mutate-data.ts
import { getAuthToken } from "./get-token";
import { getStrapiURL } from "@/lib/utils";

export async function mutateData(method: string, path: string, payload?: any) {
  const baseUrl = getStrapiURL();
  const authToken = await getAuthToken();
  const url = new URL(path, baseUrl);

  if (!authToken) throw new Error("No auth token found");

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: method,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ ...payload }),
    });

    if (method === 'DELETE') {
      return response.ok;
    }

    const data = await response?.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    throw error;
  }
}


I have already verified that the address exists, the id is correct, the route: /api/addresses/:id is correct since it is the one that strapi shows me
